# Getting a NoSuchElementsException in Java?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, tostring

Ok, so for my java class's final project we're supposed to implement a simplified version of craps that runs for 10 rounds. Whenever I run this, I get the NoSuchElementsException for the line "int b=std.nextInt()". Why is that? I opened a scanner object and whatnot, but it wont let me enter the data to proceed with the game, throwing the exception instead. I also get the same exception for the "System.out.println(now.toString());" line in the main method. How could that not have any elements?

```
public class Player {
private int bet;//how much was bet
private boolean Pass;//they chose pass
private boolean DPass;//they chose dont pass
private boolean win;//did they win?
private int money=20;//how much they have
//private String continuity="initial";

//Modifier methods
public void newBet(int x){this.bet=x;}
public void Pass(boolean x){this.Pass=x;}
public void DPass(boolean x){this.DPass=x;}
public void didYouWin(boolean x){this.win=x;}
public void newMoney(int x){this.money+=x;}
//public void keepPlaying(String s){this.continuity=s;}

//Accessor methods
public int getBet(){return this.bet;}
public boolean getPass(){return this.Pass;}
public boolean getDPass(){return DPass;}
public boolean getResult(){return this.win;}
public int getMoney(){return this.money;}
public boolean isWinning(){return this.win;}
//public String playing(){return continuity;}
public String toString(){
    return "Bet: $"+this.bet+"\nBet on Pass: "+this.Pass+"\nBet on Don't Pass: "+this.DPass+"\nMoney:S"+this.money;
}

//Constructor method
public Player(int bet, boolean pass, boolean dpass){
    this.bet=bet;
    this.Pass=pass;
    this.DPass=dpass;
}
```

}

> Actual game play code<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class trial1 {

```
public static int RollDice(){           //Method for Dice Roll
    int[] die1={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] die2={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Random r=new Random();
    int i1=r.nextInt(6-0);
    int i2=r.nextInt(6-0);
    int sum=die1[i1]+die2[i2];
    System.out.println("\nDie 1: "+die1[i1]+"\nDie 2: "+die2[i2]+"\nTotal Sum: "+sum);
    return sum; 
}

public static int Roll7(){//roll for 7
    if (RollDice()==7){
        return 2;
    }
    else return Roll7();
}

public static int PointRoll(int x){//If person rolled 4,5,6,8,9,10...
    int a=RollDice();
    if (a==x){
        return Roll7();
    }
    else if (a==7){
        return 1;
    }
    else return PointRoll(x);
}

public static int ComeOutRoll(){//1 = pass loses, 2 = pass wins, 3 = pass loses and dont pass gets nothing
    int x=RollDice();
    if ((x==2)||(x==3)) {
        return 1;
        }
    else if ((x==7)||(x==11)){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (x==12){
        return 3;
    }
    else return PointRoll(x);
}
public static Player InitializeGame(){
    //initialize stats and player
    System.out.println("Please enter how much you'd like to bet (max is $5)");
    Scanner std=new Scanner(System.in);
    int b=std.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 if you bet PASS or 2 if you bet DON'T PASS");
    int p=std.nextInt();
    boolean betpass, betdpass;
    if (p==1){
        betpass=true;
        betdpass=false;
    }
    else {
        betpass=false;
        betdpass=true;
    }
    Player name=new Player(b, betpass, betdpass);
    System.out.print(name.toString());
    std.close();
    return name;
}
public static Player BeginGame(Player name){
    //Start actual game process without the betting ie all the dice rolling and stat changing -->will return player's status
    //boolean pass=name.getPass();
    //boolean neutral=false;
    int result=ComeOutRoll();
    //find out if player won money or lost money
    if (name.getPass()){//if player bet on pass
        if (result==1){
            name.newMoney(name.getMoney()-name.getBet());
        }
        else if (result==2){
            name.newMoney(name.getMoney()+name.getBet());
        }
        else {
            name.newMoney(name.getMoney()-name.getBet());
        }
    }
    else {//if player bet dont pass
        if (result==1){
            name.newMoney(name.getMoney()+name.getBet());
        }
        else if (result==2){
            name.newMoney(name.getMoney()-name.getBet());
        }
        else {
            name.didYouWin(false);
        }

    }
    if (name.getMoney()<=0){name.didYouWin(false);}//setting win data for yes or no. IF no money, u lose
    else {name.didYouWin(true);}

public static Player Continue(Player name){//just like begin game, but adding the new bet
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter how much you'd like to bet (max is $5)");
    Scanner std=new Scanner(System.in);
    int b=std.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 if you bet PASS or 2 if you bet DON'T PASS");
    int p=std.nextInt();
    boolean betpass, betdpass;
    if (p==1){
        betpass=true;
        betdpass=false;
    }
    else {
        betpass=false;
        betdpass=true;
    }
    name.Pass(betpass);
    name.DPass(betdpass);
    name.newBet(b);
    System.out.println(name.toString());
    return BeginGame(name);
}
public static void Loss(Player name){//losing message
    System.out.println("YOU LOSE!!!!!!!! HAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!\n"+name.toString());
}
public static void End(Player name){//End game message
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
}

public static Player Run(){
    Player name = InitializeGame();
    return BeginGame(name);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Welcome to my version of craps!");
    Player now=Run();
    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        if (now.isWinning()){
            System.out.println("ROUND "+i);
            System.out.println(now.toString());
            now=Continue(now);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            Loss(now);
            System.out.print(now.toString());
            End(now);
            i=11;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That line of code is taking input from the console. When do you get the Exception thrown? Is it after the first attempt to enter your input? Or is it after some other specific amount of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The NoSuchElementsException means that you tried to get an `int` from the scanner, `std`, but there was no next `int`.  So it throws this error to let you know your input was bad.

Comment: But it's not even giving me the chance to type in the integer.

Comment: So its the first std.getInt() that is throwing the error? or the second?

Comment: Well, then the input is not an int, or it's got some space or special character inside.  try doing `System.out.println("input='"+std.next()+"');` and making sure its really an int.  Otherwise you might need to do `int b = Integer.valueOf(std.next().trim()).intValue();`

Answer (score 0):

It would seem from the NoSuchElementException that you're not reading an int from the Scanner. It is interpreting your input as some other data type.